# Rectangle Auto Blit

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a container rectangle and element rectangle, both are specified only in height and width.  Using PHP I need to figure out what positions and orientation would allow for the most possible blits of the element within the container having absolutely no overlap.

An Example :

```
$container = array(5000,2000);
$element = array(300,200);
```

The output should be an array of "blit" arrays (or objects) like so

```
$blit_object = array($x,$y,$rotation_degrees);
```

Comment: I didn't notice that "homework" was noted. Did I overlook it?

Comment: Haha.... nope, it is for a program I am writing.  I have a very ugly trial and error way of doing it, but I figure there must be cleaner way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since no one is answering me, I am just going to show my "trial and error" solution in case anyone else ever needs it.

It calculates the two basic layout options and sees which one has the most and uses that.

```
function MakeBlits($container,$element)
{
    $container_x = $container[0];
    $container_y = $container[1];
    $options = array();
    for($i = 0;$i<=1;$i++)
    {
        if($i == 0)
        {
            $element_x = $element[0];
            $element_y = $element[1];
        }
        else


{
        $element_x = $element[1];
        $element_y = $element[0];
    }
    $test_x = floor($container_x/$element_x);
    $test_y = floor($container_y/$element_y);
    $test_remainder_x = $container_x - $test_x*$element_x;
    $test_remainder_y = $container_y - $test_y*$element_y;
    $test_x2 = 0;
    $test_x3 = 0;
    $test_y2 = 0;
    $test_y3 = 0;
    if($test_remainder_x > $element_y)
    {
        $test_x2 = floor($test_remainder_x/$element_y);
        $test_y2 = floor($container_y/$element_x);
    }
    if($test_remainder_y > $element_x)
    {
        $test_x3 = floor($container_x/$element_y);
        $test_y3 = floor($test_remainder_y/$element_x);
    }
    $options[] = array(
        'total'=>($test_x*$test_y)+($test_x2*$test_y2)+($test_x3*$test_y3),
        'x'=>$test_x,
        'y'=>$test_y,
        'x2'=>$test_x2,
        'y2'=>$test_y2,
        'x3'=>$test_x3,
        'y3'=>$test_y3
    );
}
if($options[0]['total']>=$options[1]['total'])
{
    $option = $options[0];
    $rotate = 0;
    $width = $element[0];
    $height = $element[1];

}
else
{
    $option = $options[1];
    $rotate = -90;
    $width = $element[1];
    $height = $element[0];
}
$blit_objects = array();
for($i=0;$i<$option['x'];$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<$option['y'];$j++)
    {
        $blit_objects[] = array(
            'x'=>$i*$width,
            'y'=>$j*$height,
            'rotation'=>$rotate);
    }
}
for($k = 0;$k < $option['x2'];$k++)
{
    for($l = 0;$l < $option['y2'];$l++)
    {
        $blit_objects[] = array(
            'x'=>$i*$width + $k*$height,
            'y'=>$l*$width,
            'rotation'=>$rotate+90);
    }
}
for($k = 0;$k < $option['x3'];$k++)
{
    for($l = 0;$l < $option['y3'];$l++)
    {
        $blit_objects[] = array(
            'x'=>$k*$height,
            'y'=>$j*$height+$l*$width,
            'rotation'=>$rotate+90);
    }
}
return $blit_objects;
```

}